# Inconsistent behavior of pandas DatetimeIndex.round?

Tags: pandas, rounding, datetimeindex

I encountered a strange, very unexpected behavior in the round-method of pandas.DatetimeIndex:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
t1 = pd.DatetimeIndex([dt.datetime(2013,12,5,1,30,0),
                       dt.datetime(2013,12,5,2,30,0),
                       dt.datetime(2013,12,5,3,30,0),
                       dt.datetime(2013,12,5,4,30,0)])  
print(t1)
```

gives:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2013-12-05 01:30:00', '2013-12-05 02:30:00',
               '2013-12-05 03:30:00', '2013-12-05 04:30:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

So far, so good. Now I want to round to the nearest full hour. I don't mind if the next or the previous hour is chosen. But I need consistent behavior.

```
t2 = t1.round('H')
print(t2)
```

Surprisingly I get:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2013-12-05 02:00:00', '2013-12-05 02:00:00',
               '2013-12-05 04:00:00', '2013-12-05 04:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Entries 1 and 3 got rounded up while entries 2 and 4 got rounded down. Is this supposed behavior? I guess there is some numerical stuff going on under the hood. But this is really disturbing. In my case the temporal resolution is constrained to minutes. So I can add (or subtract) 1s to every time and get the desired result. But this can't be the right way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many people learn the "round half up" rule such that 1.5 is rounded to 2, 2.5 is rounded to 3, etc. This is **not** how rounding is handled in numpy. From [`numpy.around`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.around.html), emphasis my own.

> For values exactly halfway between rounded decimal values, NumPy
>   rounds **to the nearest even value**. Thus 1.5 and 2.5 round to 2.0, -0.5
>   and 0.5 round to 0.0, etc.

Thinking about your times as hour fractions, this would be the expected behavior:

```
np.around([1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5])
#array([2., 2., 4., 4.])
```

(pandas defines the same behaviour, using [`RoundTo.NEAREST_HALF_EVEN`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/arrays/datetimelike.py#L397-L398) for rounding)

---

So how do you Round Half up for a Datetime with frequencies?

Buried deep is a [`RoundTo`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_libs/tslibs/timestamps.pyx#L85-L100) method and the rounding we want is `RoundTo.NEAREST_HALF_PLUS_INFTY`. We need to deal with the complication of `datetimes`, but again pandas already handles that; also import the `round_nsint64` method.

```
from pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps import RoundTo, round_nsint64

# rounded int64s 
rounded = round_nsint64(t1.view('i8'), RoundTo.NEAREST_HALF_PLUS_INFTY, 'H')

# Convert back to datetime
pd.DatetimeIndex(rounded)
#DatetimeIndex(['2013-12-05 02:00:00', '2013-12-05 03:00:00',
#               '2013-12-05 04:00:00', '2013-12-05 05:00:00'],
#              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: Thanks. I only consulted the pandas' doc, not  numpy's. Since I don't see a way around this, I stick with my hack, add 1s to every time and keep an eye on it.

Comment: @Durtal see the update, you can use pandas to do this properly if you're willing to import some rather specific methods buried deep in the library

Comment: @ALollz I might need to create a second account just so I can upvote this again.